# Appengine Cloud Endpoints with new Google+ sign-in

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-cloud-endpoints

How does the new google+ sign-in apis fit into making authenticated calls to Cloud Endpoints.  To use OAuth with endpoints the app must request permission for the 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email' scope at a minimum.  Will using the Google+ sign-in button grant this scope?  Or am I going to have to ask my users for yet another permission??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google+ sign-in button has a "scopes" attribute that you can list additional scopes that you would like to request. You can list the userinfo.email scope there as well as any Cloud specific ones.

If you need to [retrieve a user's email address](https://developers.google.com/+/web/people), you can add the userinfo.email scope within that attribute and then use the appropriate REST end point to retrieve the address.

Additionally, to retrieve email addresses in mobile apps, see:

- [Android](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people#retrieve_an_authenticated_users_email_address)
- [iOS](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/people#retrieve_an_authenticated_users_email_address).

Comment: This is not working for me.  I just get "An internal error occured" toasted on the screen.  Have you actually done this?

Comment: I got it working.  I had to have the login scope at a minimum, I was just using userinfo.email.  I must say it is a nice flow and easy to implement!

Comment: Does this feature give you other elements of the google+ user profile? For example, the users profile picture?

Comment: sthomps@ Each of the scopes meant for use with login provide access to the profile picture if the user has one. See the list of scopes at https://devsite.googleplex.com/+/api/oauth

Answer (score 3):

The userinfo.email scope is in addition to the plus.login scope. In fact, plus.login explicitly ***doesn't*** give access to the user's email address.

Although you'll be asking for "another permission", this is all done at the same time in a single OAuth screen, so all the permissions will be listed at once. The user isn't presented with screen after screen of permissions, the request for their email will be listed along with the requests for the plus.login scope information.

Comment: Ok, I will be testing this.  Do you know about android?  If I use the new sign-in button can I include the userinfo.email scope with the same request for permission??

Comment: I do see in the documentation that you can request scopes from the PlusClient.Builder however the scopes listed are only g+ scopes.  I am going to try the userinfo.email scope and see what happens...

Comment: You should be able to add any scopes that your application requires, although I will admit that I haven't tried it out myself. This is part of the design of OAuth, however, so it "should" work.

Comment: No luck so far.  I get "An internal error occurred" toasted on screen.